# Delphi-7 WSDL Importer Error "The following types, referred to in the WSDL document are not being represented..."

Tags: web-services, delphi, wsdl

Importing NetSuite WSDL into Delphi-7 results in errors:

> `// The following types, referred to in the WSDL document are not being represented
>
>   // in this file. They are either aliases[@] of other types represented or were referred
>
>   // to but never[!] declared in the document. The types from the latter category
>
>   // typically map to predefined/known XML or Borland types; however, they could also
>  
>   // indicate incorrechtt WSDL documents that failed to declare or import a schema type.
>
>   // ************************************************************************
>  
>   // !:login           - "urn:messages_2009_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"
>
>   // !:loginResponse   - "urn:messages_2009_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"
>
>   // !:applicationInfo - "urn:messages_2009_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com"`

WSDL is at: https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2009_1_0/netsuite.wsdl
or it can be downloaded along with all XSDs from: https://system.netsuite.com/download/WSDL_v2009_1_0.zip

I saw this thread http://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=157927 but I did not find any issue with NetSuite Certificate.

Any help to solve this would be appreciated!

Comment: It works fine in Delphi 2010; if you need the generated units let me know (just email me firstname at lastname dot com).

Comment: May be it's time to update. I have similar problem with Delphi 6 and I upgrade to Delphi 2010. It will be hard to return using Delhi 6 for one big project.

Answer (score 0):

I helped harry by generating the Delphi units with the Delphi 2010 WSDL importer. They don't compile in Delphi 7.

This was his reaction:

> I could not use that file with Delphi
>   7 because Delphi 7 does not support
>   *{$SCOPEDENUMS ON}*

[Scoped Enums](http://chrisbensen.blogspot.com/2007/10/delphi-scoped-enums.html) are a nice feature, but difficult to back-port to Delphi 7.